Failed to start nmbd.service
My PC is stuck at boot with this error
Failed to start nmbd.service

Output of systemctl status nmbd.service:
  Loaded:loaded(/lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service;disabled ;preset:enabled 
Active:inactive (dead) 

Output of  sudo journalctl - xeu nmbd.service:
The unit nmbd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'timeout'
A Start job for unit nmbd.service has finished with failure
The job identifier is 1366 and the job result is failed

Output of  test parm -s | grep interfaces
      Load smb config files from /etc/samba/SMB.CONFIG Loaded services file OK. Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback) Warning: lock directory /run/samba does not exist Warning:pid directory /run/samba does not exist

Server role: Role_STANDALONE



Please post the output of journalctl --unit=nmbd.service

I meant: please add the output of the command journalctl --unit=nmbd.service to the question by editing it (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1509671/edit), you can format the output nicely by selecting it and clicking on the "{}" symbol in the editor

Please post the output of the following command: testparm -s | grep interfaces
